# Fragment discard leaves strange pixel pattern

Tags: scenekit

I've used an OpenGL ES snippet in the `SCNShadable` fragment entry point to discard portions of an object. I'm getting this result:

[image: Pixely Heart]

Is that the vertex color or a normal? Been attempting to get rid of them, but no success. The fragment snippet looks like this:

```
varying float clipFragment;

#pragma body
if (clipFragment == 1.0) {
    discard;
}
```

Seems the error is here in how I'm selecting the Geometry points to discard in this little test, because if I say clip everything, it's invisible.

```
varying float clipFragment;

#pragma body
if (_geometry.position.z >= 0.0) {
    clipFragment = 1.0;
} else {
    clipFragment = 0.0;
}
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of these pixels in the context of SceneKit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Rounding error

By changing the test in the fragment it works

```
varying float clipFragment;

#pragma transparent
#pragma body
if (clipFragment > 0.0) {
    discard;
}
```

[image: Victory]